# Displaying a modal dialog (ChildWindow) from a user control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

I have a user control that has a `Grid` as a main container. This control needs to display a modal dialog. However, when I show the dialog (implements `ChildWindow`) from the control, nothing happens, no errors and no dialog.

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.Show();
```

If `ChildWindow` is something that can only be displayed from the main page and not user control, what's my alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating a user control and putting it in the same grid location as the original control with `Visibility:Collapsed`. Every time I'd need a modal dialog, I'd disable the user control that is visible and set `Visibility:Visible` on the modal dialog user control.

This blog post helped a great deal: [Silverlight Tutorial Part 6: Using User Controls to Implement Master/Detail Scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-6-using-user-controls-to-implement-master-detail-scenarios.aspx)